# Cannot install pm2 in OS 10.15.5

Tags: node.js, pm2

`Mac os Catalina 10.15.5 / npm version 6.14.5`

When I install pm2, it seems that it is being installed without any problem.
But if I run pm2, the terminal only says that command not found.
It's not working at all. It just doesn't start.

I searched through StackOverflow and tried the following solutions.

```
- npm i -g pm2
- sudo npm install -g pm2
- npm i pm2@latest --no-optional -g --no-shrinkwrap
- sudo npm install pm2 -g --unsafe-perm
```

All of the above gives me this result.

```
/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/pm2 -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/pm2-docker -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/pm2-dev -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/pm2-runtime -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
+ pm2@4.4.0
updated 1 package in 4.768s
```

After this,

If I type `pm2` : I get `pm2-bash: pm2: command not found`
If I type `whereis pm2` : it just doesn't do anything at all.
If I type `pm2 start index.js` in VScode terminal: `zsh: command not found: pm2`

And there are the files inside of the path(`/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/`).
I don't know what the problem is.
Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those who are having the same problem, hope it helps.
After repeating countless uninstall & install of node/npm/pm2 whatsoever and toying around the permissions, I found answer by myself.

0. Changed default command shell from zsh to bash. (in VScode as well)***
1. Deleted all the node & npm and installed nvm, and re-installed node via nvm.(npm is automatically installed together).
2. Installed pm2 with npm.